# Use logical operators to return undefined if value is falsy

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display a column with a value from the database in a component of a react app. If the value is falsy I don't want to display the column.

The value fetched from the database can either be `null`, or any number 0 or greater.

```
<>
{this.state.likeCount &&
    <div className="col">
        <p>Like Count: {this.state.likeCount}<>
    </div>
}
</>
```

However, in the fragment above if `likeCount` is 0 the logical && operator will return the falsy value of 0 without the column component. Is there another operator I can use so if `likeCount` is falsy nothing gets returned instead?

I am aware I could use the conditional (ternary) operator and specify the third operand as `undefined` (`<>{likeCount ? ... : undefined}</>`) but since I always want `undefined` returned I was wondering if there was another way to do this where I don't have to specify the third operand each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick trick (logical operator(s)) to turn any value in JavaScript to a Boolean: the double NOT `!!`

```
 const value = 0
 console.log(!!value) // false
```

Or as you're asking in React, it would look closer to:

```
 {!!this.state.likeCount && (<div>foo bar</div>)}
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the OR operator as a default so an empty string or `false` or `undefined` is returned instead of `likeCount` when `likeCount` is falsy

```
<>
{
(this.state.likeCount || undefined) &&
    <div className="col">
        <p>Like Count: {this.state.likeCount}<>
    </div>
}
</>
```

In other words

```js
console.log( (0 || undefined) && 5 );  // undefined
console.log( (null || undefined) && 5 );//   undefined
console.log( (1 || undefined) && 5 ); // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

0 is considered falsy in javascript, but it seems you do want to display 0 as a value for the likeCount column.

What you need is to check if a value is nullish.

Here's a couple of things you can try.

- Nullish coalecing

  ```
  <>
    {this.state.likeCount ??
        <div className="col">
            <p>Like Count: {this.state.likeCount}<>
        </div>
    }
    </>
  ```
- Check against null

  ```
  <>
    {(this.state.likeCount !== null) &&
        <div className="col">
            <p>Like Count: {this.state.likeCount}<>
        </div>
    }
    </>
  ```